# Calculator: Name Error in Python class

Tags: python, class, variables, calculator, statements

I'm building a calculator. I'm getting the "NameError: name 'self' is not defined the statement "if self.op.Pending == True" part of my code. I tried setting something equal to None, but that didn't get rid of the error. How do I get rid of the error?

```
class calculator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0
        self.current = ""
        self.newNumber = True
        self.opPending = False
        self.op = ""
        self.eq = False

    def numberPress (self, num): 
        self.eq = False
        temp = textbox.get()
        temp2 = str(num)

    if self.newNumber:
        self.current = temp2
        self.newNumber = False
    else:
        if temp2 == '.':
            if temp2 in temp:
                return
            self.current = temp + temp2
            self.display(self.current)

    def calcTotal(self):
        self.eq = True
        self.currrent = float(self.current)

    if self.opPending == True: #ERROR
        self.doSum()
    else:
            self.total = float(textbox.get())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` is not defined outside of your individual functions, which is why in each function you have to call `def func(self...):`

Thus, call that in a function:

```
class calculator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0
        self.current = ""
        self.newNumber = True
        self.opPending = False
        self.op = ""
        self.eq = False

    def numberPress (self, num): 
        self.eq = False
        temp = textbox.get()
        temp2 = str(num)

        if self.newNumber:
            self.current = temp2
            self.newNumber = False
        else:
            if temp2 == '.':
                if temp2 in temp:
                    return
                self.current = temp + temp2
                self.display(self.current)

    def calcTotal(self):
        self.eq = True
        self.currrent = float(self.current)

    def call(self):
        if self.opPending == True: #ERROR
            self.doSum()
        else:
            self.total = float(textbox.get())
```

Comment: Thank, can't believe I forgot about that! Now, time for me to build the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have indentation errors:

This is everything that counts towards `numpress`:

```
def numberPress (self, num): 
        self.eq = False
        temp = textbox.get()
        temp2 = str(num)
```

And the next lines are "**outside**" of the function:

```
 if self.newNumber:
        self.current = temp2
        self.newNumber = False
    else:
        if temp2 == '.':
            if temp2 in temp:
                return
            self.current = temp + temp2
            self.display(self.current)
```

The same thing happens in `def calcTotal(self):`.

To fix this you simply have to add 4 spaces to the lines that are "**outside**"